# Help identify my Hungarian minhagim

Tags: halacha, minhag, ashkenazi, genealogy

My paternal grandfather was from a little mountain town in Czechoslovakia called Giraltovce. As far as I know, their minhagim were basically just Hungarian (as opposed to Chassidish or Oberlander). I would like to identify my minhag because my zeide didn’t talk much about his upbringing and genealogically I can only get back to my great-grandfather.

Here are some examples if they help at all:

- We stand for kiddush and havdalah always
- We don’t wear a tallis until married
- We daven Ashkenaz and have Ashkenaz tefillin
- Zeide kept gebrokts privately
- Eating in the sukkah Shmini Atzeres night and then only Kiddush/HaMotzi in the morning

Thanks!

Comment: Correct me if I’m wrong, but many minhagei chasidei satmar are more hungarian than they are chassidish…

Comment: Could be; would be hard to figure out what came before and what came from the Yismach Moshe or the Rebbes

Comment: it seems from the info you've provided that many of the customs are general eastern european customs. do you know if he wore tefillin on chol hamoed

Comment: Yes, without a brachah. We keep it on for first day Pesach ChM until after laining. My father has also said it’s just “Eastern European Ashkenaz”, but I did not know that is a real category. A resource for the general minhagim would be great

Comment: in general people do not write books on minhagim (with exception to chabad). you have better luck asking someone or searching the internet for a blog post or something

Comment: This is a typical Hungarian "Ashkenazi" minhag. You'll find this one in Schlesinger siddurim and machzorim, in Rödelheim as "Polish" and in general as "Böhmen-Mähren und Ungarn." But what is the question?

Comment: You might be better off researching the general minhagim/background of the city of Giraltovce.

Comment: I have. There’s not much on that topic.